# In DRF, How to inject full `ErrorDetail` in the response, using a custom exception handler?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using a pretty complex custom handler in DRF.
For example, for a given response, `response.data` could look like to:

```py
{'global_error': None, 'non_field_errors': [], 'field_errors': {'important_field': [ErrorDetail(string='Ce champ est obligatoire.', code='required')]}}
```

However, when getting the actual response from the API, the `ErrorDetail` will be transformed in a simple string, losing the code information.

Is there a simple way to ensure `ErrorDetail` is always written in a response as `{"message": "...", "code": "..."}` without transforming the response manually in the custom handler?

I know there exists the DRF `get_full_details()` method that returns exactly this on an exception. But I'm the response level.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're using it, but you could use `custom_exception_handler` to transform any exceptions raised to the format you provide. Here is an example:

```
def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
   response = exception_handler(exc, context)
   if response is not None:
      response.data["timestamp"] = datetime.now().isoformat()
      response.data["error_type"] = exc.__class__.__name__
      response.data["path"] = context["request"].path

   return response
```

Using it this is what it produced:

```
 {
  "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided.",
  "timestamp": "2024-03-29T20:09:02.228370",
  "error_type": "NotAuthenticated",
  "path": "/tools/"
}
```

P.S.: It also can take the detail as the exception raised from `validate` in serializers.

Here are the docs: [custom_execption_handler](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling)